# executing service (openoffice headless) in chroot is slow

Tags: linux, system, call, chroot, strace

I created an ubuntu chroot environment (using debootstrap) and started openoffice as a service to convert files using unoconv. It works but it spends about 20s to do conversions which are below 1s outside chroot jail. Stracing it I can see that this extra time is spent in some socket operations whose timeout expires, the same operations that work well without a chroot environment. However, similar operations works fine.

Any suggestion?

---

starting server (chrooted):

```
soffice -invisible -headless -nologo -nodefault "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8301;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" -env:UserInstallation=ootest2
```

calling it (chrooted too):

```
strace unoconv -f pdf -p 8300 simple_test.docx
```

timeout trace:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "M#\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\tlocalhost\6(none)\10mo"..., 47, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 47
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 0 (Timeout)
close(4)                                = 0
```

similar trace without timeout (same unoconv operation):

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(4, "M#\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\tlocalhost\6(none)\10mo"..., 47, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 47
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [47])                = 0
recvfrom(4, "M#\201\202\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\tlocalhost\6(none)\10mo"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 47
close(4)                                = 0
```

chroot details:

- using dchroot to use it as a normal user
- mounted dev, proc, etc as (fstab):

  /tmp                    /var/local/chrootest/tmp
  /dev                    /var/local/chrootest/dev
  /sys                    /var/local/chrootest/sys
  proc-chroot             /var/local/chrootest/proc
  devpts-chroot           /var/local/chrootest/dev/pts

Comment: The socket operation that's failing is a DNS lookup.  Specifically, it's trying to connect to a DNS server at `127.0.0.1`.  Does your chroot'ed environment have an `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Yes, it has /etc/hosts, and include the line "127.0.0.1 localhost"

I also thought that was something about DNS/DNS lookup, so I put a simple server (require 'socket'; puts TCPServer.new("localhost", 8400).accept.readline) and a simple client (require 'socket'; TCPSocket.new("localhost", 8400).write("hi\n")) in ruby, chrooted, and it worked.

Comment: Out of ideas, then, sorry :(  Sounds like something possibly specific to OpenOffice.

Comment: Thanks for trying ;) I have solved the problem using pipes to communicate with openoffice server, but still don't know why sockets were failing :(

Comment: I was able to overcome the problem by passing the LAN IP address to unoconv both when starting the listener and the converter:

`unoconv -s 10.136.19.163 -l`
`unoconv -s 10.136.19.163 -f doc index.html`

Answer (score 3):

unoconv does some wack DNS lookups.  I added this to my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.(none)
```

And it made things significantly better.